# Excel VBA To AutoFill Column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

In Column A I have a list of 5 names - I am wanting to in column B create the different Teams and name them Team_1, Team_2 etc etc

This is the syntax I have tried...

```
Function AutoFill()
  Dim KCLR As Long
  KCLR = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("B2").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Team_1"
  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:" & KCLR)
End Function
```

However, on the line `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:" & KCLR)` I get an error of

> Range("B2:" & KCLR) = Method 'Range' Of Object '_Global' failed

What do I need to do in order for this to successfully  `AutoFill` as I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:" & KCLR)` should be `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & KCLR)` as `KCLR` is returning a number.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I was close - still need to enhance my VBA skills!

Answer (score 1):

Following @harun24hr answer, for future better coding practice, avoid using `Select` , `ActiveCell` and `Selection`, and use fully qualified `Range`s.

See example below:

```
Function AutoFill()

  Dim KCLR As Long

  KCLR = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "Team_1"
  Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & KCLR)

End Function
```